# Android Studio - New activity after scan

Tags: java, android

I've this code in Java Android APP that is launched after a camera scan. How Can i go to new activity after a scan?

```
ActivityResultLauncher<ScanOptions> barLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ScanContract(), result ->{
        if (result.getContents()!=null){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(QRScanActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Result");
            builder.setMessage(result.getContents());
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            }).show();
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Right now, after use of the camera you are raising an `AlertDialog`. Do you want go to another activity instead of this, or only when the user clicks "OK"?

Comment: I Want another activity instead of the dialog

Answer (score 0):

So you are observing a dialog after scanned something, so the following part is the `callback` of your scanning event:

```java
if (result.getContents()!=null){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(QRScanActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Result");
    builder.setMessage(result.getContents());
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    }).show();
}
```

So all you need to do, is to replace the above code into code that triggers a new Activity:

```java
if (result.getContents() != null) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(QRScanActivity.this, NextTargetActivity.class);
  // You can also put the scanned result contents using intent.putExtra()
  startActivity(intent);
}
```